# Convert ASCII values to Double value

Tags: java, android, ascii

How to convert **ASCII values** to **double value**?

Input (ASCII values):

> 48, 48, 52, 56, 55, 57, 53, 57, 54, 49

Output expected (double value):

> 487.959,61

I tried like this, but still not worked. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
byte[] ascii = new byte[]{48, 48, 52, 56, 55, 57, 53, 57, 54, 49};
long lngAscii = ByteBuffer.wrap(ascii).getLong();
double result = lngAscii/100;
Log.i("result:", String.valueOf(result));  // result: 5.2085034998064304E16
```

Comment: First, that `byte[]` contains "HHRVUWSWTI" in ASCII. Second, it is 10 bytes, a `double` is 8 bytes. Why do you expect that particular value?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think its a string, and he's expecting the string to read "487.959,61"  in ascii.  Notice that that string is 10 characters long.  Of course he still had the wrong values for that.

Comment: Did you mean `0x30,0x30,0x34,0x38,0x37,0x39,0x35,0x39,0x36,0x31`? And how are you supposed to know where the decimal point is supposed to go?

Comment: @Elliott, you are right. I entered incorrect input, it should be a decimal array, not a hex array. I have changed it. Thanks.

Comment: @EJP, yes I entered incorrect input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could hardly be more wrong. You've written decimal ASCII values, arbitrarily stuck 0x in front of them all, then misinterpreted that as a binary value, then divided by the wrong divisor. However:

```
byte[] ascii = {48, 48, 52, 56, 55, 57, 53, 57, 54, 49};
long lngAscii = Long.parseLong(new String(ascii));
double result = lngAscii/100000;
Log.i("result:", String.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: Thank you brother for the help. My problem is solved. :)